# Can "leaf" be used to mean "sheet" or "page"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

I have recently stumbled upon somebody saying:

> I have decided to turn over a new leaf.

I was already aware of a similar expression with "page" instead. I have also heard of "leaflet" meaning (as far as I can tell) "flyer" or somesuch.

So can a leaf mean a page? In Finnish they can be interchanged in some rare cases. I had never heard of this in English though.

"Leaf" seems to be defined here as a double-sided page from a piece of paper folded vertically (courtesy of a quick bit of Googling):

http://www.indiana.edu/~libpres/manual/treatments/glospages/folio.html

Can the words be interchanged in general usage?

Comment: It's great that you found one of the answers helpful but you may want to wait a few days before accepting an answer - see [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161) on meta for some reasons why.

Comment: OK, this is my first question on any linguistics stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no they can't be generally interchanged.

According to [this dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/turn--over--a--new--leaf), leaf can mean

> Bibliography. a unit generally comprising two printed, blank, or illustrated pages of a book, one on each side.

So that's like a book open on a table, and when you flip the page, you're revealing a new leaf.

If you just have a single paper on a table and flip it over, it isn't revealing a new leaf (because it was never a leaf in the first place)

Thank you for asking this question though! I'd actually never really thought about the phrase, and always generally assumed it was talking about a leaf like on a tree (why you would turn over a new one I never considered).

Comment: Thanks. In Finnish "leaf" is somewhat more broad: it can even mean "newspaper".

Answer (score 0):

In:

> I have decided to **turn over a new leaf**.

*turn over a new leaf* is an idiomatic usage. See [***turn over a new leaf***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83225/can-leaf-be-used-to-mean-sheet-or-page):

> *Fig.* to begin again, fresh; to reform and begin again. (Fig. on turning to a fresh page.  The leaf is a page—a fresh, clean page.)
>   *I have made a mess of my life. I'll turn over a new leaf and hope to do better. Why don't you turn over a new leaf and surprise everyone with your good characteristics*?

*leaf* also has a number of page related definitions. This can be checked in a dictionary.